# How does the Spring Boot redirects all requests to Dispatcher Servlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When I started learning spring boot I learnt that all the requests are by default redirected to Dispatcher Servlet before reaching any Controller/Servlet.Dont we need to configure that all requests should reach Dispatcher Servlet first as we do in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot does it "automagically" with @SpringBootApplication. DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration is included in @SpringBootApplication (EnableAutoConfiguration).
Maybe this [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/restful-web-services-spring-boot-auto-configure) will give you some start point.